# Accessing the short-arched f in EB Garamond

Tags: ebgaramond

Long-arched fs tend inappropriately to touch their successors, and one
often desires a narrower alternative, for example when the next letter
is 'ä'.  This is achieved by the calt feature, IF the \strike{newest}
original version of the font, which is not in texlive, is installed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[RawFeature=+calt]

\begin{document}
gefährlich fahren
\end{document}
```

---

But sometimes one wants the short f in situations that weren't
anticipated by the designers.  It is possible to specify this every
time, by doing something like

```
\newcommand\f{\symbol{"F0367}}
\f$'$
```

But is it also possible to

- disable the long f completely;
- specify that an f followed by a prime should always be short?

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ? When I run your MWE on my system (MacTeX2019 on MacOS 10.13.6), I get exactly the desired result: a short-armed `f` for `gefährlich` and a long-armed `f` for `fahren`.

Comment: @Mico, LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) -- on Arch Linux

Comment: Hmmm, that's exactly my setup too (under MacOSX). The font file itself is `/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf`, and when I type `otfinfo -v EBGaramond12-Regular.otf` at a command prompt, the answer is `Version 0.016`. Sure enough, version 0.16 is the current version. What's installed on your system?

Comment: @Mico, all right, maybe there's an ebgaramond in texlive that's different .. I don't think I have it installed apart from texlive

Comment: Your log file (toward the very end) should tell you exactly which font file is in use. What do you learn if you run `otfinfo -v` on that file?

Comment: @Mico, 
% otfinfo -v EBGaramond-Regular.otf
Version 1.000;PS 001.000;hotconv 1.0.88;makeotf.lib2.5.64775

Comment: @Mico the ebgaramond in texlive certainly don't have the calt-feature. I checked.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Wow, that's really unexpected (for me at least).

Answer (score 10):

There are *two* flavors of EB Garamond. The “original” one by Georg Duffner is still available following directions at http://georgduffner.at and it has the `calt` feature.

CTAN and TeX Live have a “new” version, prepared by Octavio Pardo. This version lacks a `calt` version.

I downloaded the “original” version from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/ and unzipped the archive. Modifying your example into

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
  Path=./EBGaramond-0.016/otf/,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*12-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*12-Italic,
  RawFeature=+calt,
]

\begin{document}
gefährlich fahren
\end{document}
```

the output is as advertised.

[image]

The “original” version has a much richer set of features:

```
> otfinfo -f EBGaramond-0.016/otf/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf 
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
calt    Contextual Alternates
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
ccmp    Glyph Composition/Decomposition
cv01    Character Variants 1
cv02    Character Variants 2
cv03    Character Variants 3
cv06    Character Variants 6
cv11    <unknown feature>
cv21    <unknown feature>
cv27    <unknown feature>
cv47    <unknown feature>
cv80    <unknown feature>
cv81    <unknown feature>
cv82    <unknown feature>
cv83    <unknown feature>
cv90    <unknown feature>
cv91    <unknown feature>
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
hlig    Historical Ligatures
kern    Kerning
lfbd    Left Bounds
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
mark    Mark Positioning
mkmk    Mark to Mark Positioning
numr    Numerators
onum    Oldstyle Figures
ordn    Ordinals
pnum    Proportional Figures
rtbd    Right Bounds
salt    Stylistic Alternates
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
size    Optical Size
smcp    Small Capitals
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
ss02    Stylistic Set 2
ss05    Stylistic Set 5
ss06    Stylistic Set 6
ss07    Stylistic Set 7
ss20    Stylistic Set 20
subs    Subscript
sups    Superscript
tnum    Tabular Figures
xtex    <unknown feature>
```

The “new” version has

```
> otfinfo -f /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Regular.otf
aalt    Access All Alternates
c2pc    Petite Capitals From Capitals
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
frac    Fractions
hist    Historical Forms
hlig    Historical Ligatures
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
mark    Mark Positioning
mkmk    Mark to Mark Positioning
onum    Oldstyle Figures
ordn    Ordinals
pcap    Petite Capitals
pnum    Proportional Figures
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
smcp    Small Capitals
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
ss02    Stylistic Set 2
ss03    Stylistic Set 3
ss04    Stylistic Set 4
ss05    Stylistic Set 5
ss06    Stylistic Set 6
ss07    Stylistic Set 7
subs    Subscript
sups    Superscript
swsh    Swash
tnum    Tabular Figures
```

Comment: Why is TeX Live including an apparently inferior version? Or is there an advantage somewhere?