# Ligatures with EB Garamond

Tags: xetex, ligatures, ebgaramond

My minimal non-working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
This is a test. Quisque
{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+hlig}standard, acta, \textit{speak, skies, standard, select}}
\end{document}
```

I got the code of `\addfontfeature` from [EB Garamond's specimen file](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/blob/master/specimen/Specimen.tex). However, I'm not getting the ligatures as they should appear. Does anyone have a clue to how to get them to work? I'm not a font expert :-(

Comment: there are two flavours of EB Garamond. The specimen file describes the one which is *not* in texlive. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503167/2388.

Comment: That link helped indeed. I had downloaded the OTF files from that site and put them in my current directory, but it was apparently taking the files from texlive. Specifying the path and the font files, fixed the issue. Thanks!